# What happens when you add a tensor with a numpy array?

Tags: python, tensorflow

### tensorflow 1.6

I was very surprised when I noticed that the following code works:

```
a = tf.constant(5)
b = a + np.array(25)
b.eval() # 30
```

I was expecting that this throws an error.
How does tensorflow handle this case? Is the numpy array added as a constant tensor to the graph so that everything can still be run on GPU? Or will there be some break to compute things on CPU?

In other words, are there any drawbacks in writing it this way, in contrast to defining a proper tf.constant tensor by hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, when you add a NumPy array to a TensorFlow tensor, TensorFlow will convert the NumPy array to a [`tf.constant`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) operation and then add it to the tensor (the same applies to about any other Python operator). So in that case actually two nodes are added to the graph, one for the constant array and one for the addition.

This makes for a more seamless interaction between the libraries, although one should be careful not to cram the graph with many copies of the same array, especially if it is big. If you are going to operate the same array several times with TensorFlow tensors, it is better to convert it to a [`tf.constant`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) first and then use it as many times as you need.

Comment: thanks! is this a new feature or did I just miss it?

Comment: @Pepe I think this has always been the case, although I can't tell for sure. Actually, to be more precise, what TF uses all the time (for most operations and function parameters) is [`tf.convert_to_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor), which takes "anything" and converts it into a tensor (if it's not already a tensor, that is).

Comment: that's what I suspected. thank you, you've been very helpful.